# systemd: How to get rid of "fake instance"?

Tags: systemd

I wrote a systemd service unit that allows multiple instances to be created. A wrapper script reads configuration details for the instance from a common config file, building the actual command to execute.  So far this works `(start,` `stop`, `status`).

However when I specify an instance that could not be found (called "fake instance") in the configuration file, my `ExecStart` command fails (as intended).  No command besides the wrapper script (which terminates, of course) is started then.

Unfortunately systemd goes crazy then:  It repeatedly tries to restart the "fake instance". Every `status` command reports an error, and I'm also unable to `stop` that fake instance.  So even that nothing is running, systemd has some knowledge about that "fake instance". How can I remove that?

Is there a special exit code that makes systemd forget about the instance immediately? (I could try `RestartPreventExitStatus=` in the mean time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "systemctl reset-failed" on the unit.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Could you please specify more what that does? We appreciate your answer but it's better to include some kind of reference or/and explanation.

Comment: Does "on the unit" mean something like `systemctl reset-failed unit@something`? It seems it works even without `unit@something`.

Comment: Literally, the first sence of the "systemctl reset-failed" documentation answers that. Quoting: "Reset the "failed" state of the specified units, or if no unit name is passed, reset the state of all units."